# JUnit : How to mock POJO class with random values filled automatically

Tags: java, junit, pojo

Is any easy way to create POJO classes and fill random values in JUnit for easy testing ?

Example :

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setName(name);
student.setAddress(address);
student.setAge(age)
--- 
---
studentService.save(student);
```

Basically I am looking to create the POJO classes easily without spending time to fill the random values. The intention is to test the service layer or controller layer with the data.

Comment: Use Lombok to generate POJO and don't test autogenerated methods.

Comment: Perhpas, I couldnt write what I really meant. Edited the title and description

Comment: For mocking you can use Mockito.

Comment: Well, normally you only mock things that you cant create for real. Adding a dependency to a mocking framework just for POJOs sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with [PODAM](https://mtedone.github.io/podam/)

Gradle dependency

```
testImplementation 'uk.co.jemos.podam:podam:7.2.5.RELEASE'
```

Example

```
PodamFactory podamFactory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
Student student = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(Student.class);
```